# additional Social icons in ShareThis module

Tags: social-network

I am using [ShareThis module](https://www.drupal.org/project/sharethis) for social icons. Can anybody please tell me how to add a new social icon not provided by this module? `Flickr`,`Feed` and `Email` icons are not present in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using [Social Media Links Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_media_links) module.

> The modules provides a configurable block that display links (icons)
>   to your profiles on various popular networking sites.

For Flicker, use [Flicker](https://www.drupal.org/project/flickr) module.

Comment: Thanku @NishantP, but `flickr` is not there